# Changing the process ID (PID) in Linux

Tags: linux, process, pid

Is it possible to change the PID in Linux? If anyone know, please tell me.

Requirement: actually I want to bring up the back ground process to foreground, which is being run under the *`init`*. So if I can change the PID or parent PID of the process, I can achieve my goal.

Comment: I think you're talking about job control, but I don't think you understand what you're asking.  Try adding some more information to clarify.

Comment: While you could probably hack the internals to change pid/ppid, a background task is likely in daemon mode and won't have stdout/stderr open, or redirected to files elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do such a thing on Unix. You might be able to use `fork` to achieve this effect, but you have to tell us what you are trying to achieve.

```
pid_t pid;

/* I want a new PID. */
pid fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    /* getpid() will show I've got a new PID. */
else
    _exit(0); /* Parent or check for -1 (tinfoil hat)
```

Obviously, like I said before, you "might" be able to use this.

Comment: actually i want to bring up the back ground process to fore ground , which is being run under the init. So if i can change the process id or parent process id of the process. i can achieve my goal.

Comment: @pavun_cool I'm not sure I understand what you mean by foreground and background.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: pocess id's(PID) are generated by the system, and are unique, and generated when the app starts. You cannot control the way they are generated...

Comment: In Linux a root user can influence the PID given to a process by writing one less of the desired PID number to `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid` (e.g. https://criu.org/Pid_restore) and a non-root user can cycle through the entire PID space (e.g. https://github.com/twosigma/set_ns_last_pid).