# When can a process change its PID on Windows?

Tags: windows, process

Is there a way for a process to change its PID on Windows? I have found this question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692667/changing-the-process-id-in-linux), but it states the answer (which is 'No') only for Linux. What about Windows?

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692667/changing-the-process-id-in-linux)] [Changing the Process Id in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692667/changing-the-process-id-in-linux)

Comment: On Linux you cannot change the pid

Comment: I don't think it can be done on windows either - it makes little sense to do it.

Comment: (Note that the answer in that other question is "No")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot change the PID of a Windows Process.