# Open process with specific pid in python

Tags: python, process, pid

How can I open a process in python with **specific pid**. I mean i want to ***set*** process PID.

**Edit:**

I want determine PID of process which i have been ran with process (e.g. using `Popen` method of `subprocess` class)

Comment: You want to determine the PID of *what*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIDs are given by the OS, you cannot use a specific PID for your subprocess.

To determine the PID of a subprocess, you can ask the subprocess for it:

```
import subprocess

dateProc = subprocess.Popen([ 'date' ])
print dateProc.pid
```

If you meant you want to know the PID of the current process, use `os.getpid()`.

Comment: I know how to get PID of subprocess, but i want to set PID myself

Comment: PID setting is is not possible.  You fork a process and get the PID of the child process as a result.  I know of no OS which would allow you to set it.  Your only chance of "setting" it would be to create subprocesses until you get the desired PID (they are used in a round-robin way, to you might end up with the wanted PID eventually).  But I'm curious:  Why do you want to have a specific PID?  What is the use case of this?

Answer (score 2):

If it is required to know the process ID of a process (e.g. firefox) the following code works for me (in Linux env). Before running the code, need to install **psutil** module in the env. And to install psutil, use '**easy_install psutil**' command.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import psutil

process = filter(lambda p: p.name == "firefox", psutil.process_iter())
for i in process:
  print i.name,i.pid
```

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the PID of (for example) 'pythoh' process, you need, at least, two lines of code:

```
import subprocess
pid = int(subprocess.Popen(['pgrep','python'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readline()[:-1])
```

Add a try-except clause if there's a chance that no process with that name is running.

If there are many 'python' processes, iterate reading lines until '' is returned.

You may need to *sudo apt-get install pgrep* too.

It is **NOT** possible to **SET** PID ==> [Changing the Process Id in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692667/changing-the-process-id-in-linux)

Comment: Guys i know how to retrive PID. I want to set PID

Comment: Sorry, but what you are doing is to be done by just `os.getpid()`.

Comment: Alfe, it was just a generic example. You can use 'getty' for example instead of 'python', and retrieve **several** PIDs. Anyway, it's not what SuB is asking for.

Comment: SuB, your question is already responded here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692667/changing-the-process-id-in-linux -- Short answer: it is NOT possible